# Efficient way to cache and access DB Data?

Tags: c++, caching, static, sqlanywhere

I have a Program (in C++) where a users scans a barcode, to look-up information (from sqlanywhere 12 DB) on the object referenced by this barcode.
While there are thousands of barcodes scanned per day, some of the attached information never changes (i.e an ID the references a common data-set, like a status).

What I would like to do is cache some of this common data, which very rarely changes (maybe once a year). 
I can handle these rare changes (worse case, I can yell out the hall to restart the programm (it is in-house)).

So the question is:

**What is the most efficient way to cache (and access) this data.**

I thought about creating a simple class, with some data structs and static lists, caching in the list, then grabbing from the list.

Then I thought maybe this isn't very efficient???

Example:

```
struct my_cache_data
{
    INDEX      id;
    CString    name;
};

static std::list<my_cache_data>    s_my_cached_list;
static CCrtiticalSection           s_crit;

void Get_Data(my_cache_data &data, INDEX id)
{
    static std::list<my_cache_data>::iterator    it;

    for(it = s_my_cached_list; it != s_my_cached_list; ++it)
    {
        if((*it).id == id)
        {
            data = *it;
            return;
        }
    }
    Cache_data(data, id);
}

void Cache_data(my_cache_data &data, INDEX id)
{
    ... Do DB stuff
    s_my_cached_list.push_back(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it yourself then I'd suggest [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) instead of [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list).

Refer to and compare the complexity of store and retrieve operations for [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) and [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map). I assume that the `id` in your case is always unique for an entry i.e. it acts like a primary key (PK) as in case of DB table. So, using [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map), you would get average constant time i.e. `O(1)` in case of search.

If your use-case involves sorting, you can look at [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map). But, I doubt that.

In addition, if you want to have a full-fledged caching system with advanced features then you might want to consider [Redis](https://redis.io/) for this.

Comment: Unfortunately my std lib doesn't have unordered_map, but it does have map (I don't want to add any libs at this point). Map looks like it should be faster, and yes my ID is unique. Thanks!

Comment: @Bob: You are welcome! :) Go with `std::map` then. It'll serve the purpose.

Comment: I've implemented my new cache, and have managed to shave 3 seconds off my look-up time (was 5 sec), thank you again

Comment: @Bob: That's awesome! :) But, why 2 seconds? What is the size of data-set where you get 2 seconds lookup time? And, what is the largest data-set (worst case scenario) that you anticipate to have in-memory in this cache?

Comment: The data is scattered all over the flippin' place. The user scans a Production Order, then the program needs to grab all related data, test it for potential changes, that may effect production flow, then calculate a 'map' of workstations that need to be run and in which sequence, in some case also break a larger order in multiple smaller ones, and then create a parallel map, and bring the pieces together again after production.

Comment: The longer look-up time is only first scan, latter scans only test for changes, and are usually much faster.

Comment: Oh and size-wise, I tested with caching company wide (would normally be localize to department) and cache was around 6MB. The time difference mainly comes from the fact that now I pull the majority of data in two SQL statements, rather than having to grab it as I go.

Comment: @Bob: Oh, wow! Got it. That's a lot of I/O. That should take some time. :-)